# Patience satisfied

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word which describes the resolution of patience.

Example 1: If someone is waiting (being patient) in a room for his/her name to be called and it finally happens.

This also might include the act of running out of patience

Example 2: If someone is waiting (being patient) in a room for his/her name to be called and the office closes before the patient is called and the patient is forced to leave.

What is that resolution or action called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Assuagement](http://school_en.enacademic.com/25211/assuagement)** Freedom, especially from pain: alleviation, ease, mitigation, palliation, relief.

Comment: I think this is closer to what I was asking, that is, the more generic relief of patience, not just the positive result of being patient.

Answer (score 5):

You've waited almost 5 minutes for an answer to this question, and now your patience has been **rewarded**.

Comment: How very *meta*.

Comment: What @kyle said - [***patience rewarded** is the mantra for this answer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22patience+rewarded+is+the+mantra%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Not sure that waiting around a room and being asked to leave is a reward.